# Webcrawler - Fetch links

Tags: f#

I'm trying to crawl a webpage, and get all the links, and add them to a `list<string>` which will be returned in the end, from the function.

My code:

```
let getUrls s : seq<string> =
    let doc = new HtmlDocument() in 
              doc.LoadHtml s

    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes "//a[@href]"
    |> Seq.map(fun z -> (string z.Attributes.["href"]))

let crawler uri : seq<string> =
    let rec crawl url =
      let web = new WebClient() 
      let data = web.DownloadString url
      getUrls data |> Seq.map crawl (* <-- ERROR HERE *)

    crawl uri
```

The problem is that at the last line in the crawl function (the getUrls seq.map...), it simply throws an error:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a     string -> 'a     but given a     string
>   -> seq<'a>     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a'
>   and 'seq<'a>'

Comment: Seq.collect to the rescue! :)

Comment: @Mauricio : You should post that as an answer. ;-]

Comment: BTW: For inspiration, there are some web crawling snippets on F# Snippets. See for example: http://www.fssnip.net/3K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crawl` is returning `unit`, but is expected to return `seq<string>`. I think you want something like:

```
let crawler uri =
  let rec crawl url =
    seq {
      let web = new WebClient() 
      let data = web.DownloadString url
      for url in getUrls data do
        yield url
        yield! crawl url
    }
  crawl uri
```

Adding a type annotation to `crawl` should point out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think something like this:

```
let crawler (uri : seq<string>) =
    let rec crawl url =
        let data = Seq.empty
        getUrls data 
        |> Seq.toList
        |> function
            | h :: t -> 
                crawl h
                t |> List.iter crawl
            | _-> ()

    crawl uri
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch links:

```
    open System.Net
    open System.IO
    open System.Text.RegularExpressions

    type Url(x:string)=
     member this.tostring = sprintf "%A" x
     member this.request  = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(x)
     member this.response = this.request.GetResponse()
     member this.stream   = this.response.GetResponseStream()
     member this.reader   = new System.IO.StreamReader(this.stream)
     member this.html     = this.reader.ReadToEnd()

    let linkex                = "href=\s*\"[^\"h]*(http://[^&\"]*)\""

    let getLinks (txt:string) = [ 
                                 for m in Regex.Matches(txt,linkex) 
                                 -> m.Groups.Item(1).Value 
                                 ]

    let collectLinks (url:Url) =   url.html
                                |> getLinks
```